# Return a single element from a nested lookup using an or query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following database:

**Requests** Collection

```
{
    "_id" : "m5tkeDo",
    "CourseId" : "KcfEGbZlyP",
    "QuizId" : "lMJkv81LyU",
    "QuestionId" : "DF9WeKATyf",
    ...
}
```

**Quizzes** Collection

```
{
    "_id" : "lMJkv81LyU",
    ...
    "MultipleChoiceQuestions" : [],
    "MultipleSelectQuestions" : [],
    "TrueOrFalse" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "DF9WeKATyf",
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Using a lookup I'm able to get the `Quiz` from the `Request`:

```
db.getCollection('Requests').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: "m5tkeDo" } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Quizzes",
            localField: "QuizId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Quiz"
         }
     },
     { $unwind: "$Quiz" }
]);
```

That returns something like this

```
{
    "_id" : "m5tkeDo",
    "QuizId" : "lMJkv81LyU",
    "QuestionId" : "DF9WeKATyf",
    ...
    "Quiz" : {
        "_id" : "lMJkv81LyU",
        ...
        "MultipleChoiceQuestions" : [],
        "MultipleSelectQuestions" : [],
        "TrueOrFalse" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "DF9WeKATyf",
                ...
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, can I get the question, which is an object in the `TrueOrFalse` array of the `Quiz`?  It is unknown whether the collection will be an item of the `TrueOrFalse`, `MultipleChoiceQuestions`, or `MultipleSelectQuestions` array so I need to look within all of them.

The end result is something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "m5tkeDo",
    "QuizId" : "lMJkv81LyU",
    "QuestionId" : "DF9WeKATyf",
    ...
    "Quiz" : {
        ...
    },
    "Question": {
      "_id" : "DF9WeKATyf",
       ...
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.getCollection('Requests').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: "m5tkeDo" } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Quizzes",
            localField: "QuizId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Quiz"
        }
    }, { $unwind: '$Quiz' },
    {
        $addFields: {
            QuestionIdObj: {
                $arrayElemAt: [{
                    $filter: {
                        input: { $concatArrays: ["$Quiz.MultipleChoiceQuestions", "$Quiz.MultipleSelectQuestions", "$Quiz.TrueOrFalse"] },
                        as: "item",
                        cond: { $eq: ["$$item._id", '$QuestionId'] }
                    }
                }, 0]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This will work even if `QuestionId` exists in any of 3 arrays or even in all 3 arrays. `QuestionIdObj` will either be a required object or `null` as we're doing `$filter`, it will return `null`(In case no `QuestionId` match found in concat'd array of three arrays).

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "m5tkeDo",
    "CourseId" : "KcfEGbZlyP",
    "QuizId" : "lMJkv81LyU",
    "QuestionId" : "DF9WeKATyf",
    "Quiz" : {
        "_id" : "lMJkv81LyU",
        "MultipleChoiceQuestions" : [],
        "MultipleSelectQuestions" : [],
        "TrueOrFalse" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "DF9WeKATyf"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "DF9WeKATyf1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "QuestionIdObj" : {
        "_id" : "DF9WeKATyf"
    }
}
```